# Cumulative distribution function of a squared laplace random variable

Tags: self-study, distributions, cumulative-distribution-function, laplace-distribution

I am trying to calculate $F_Y(x)$ (CDF) of $Y=X^2$ where $X$ is a random variable of Laplace Distribution $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-|x|}$ (let's take a simple case when parameters $\mu=0$ and $b=1$).

So here is how I tried to do it:
$$F_Y(x) = P(Y \le x) = P(X^2 \le x) = P(|X| \le \sqrt{x})$$

$$F_Y(x) = P(-\sqrt{x} < X < \sqrt{x}) = F_X(\sqrt{x}) - F_X(-\sqrt{x})$$

Since the [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) is $F_X(x)= \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}sgn(x)(1-\exp(-|x|))$ 
So, $F_Y$ should be

$$F_Y(x) = (1-\exp(-|\sqrt{x}|))sgn(\sqrt{x})$$

Is this a right approach?

And considering that $X^2$ should always be $X^2 \geq 0 $ can I say that $sgn(\sqrt{x}) \geq 0$ in this case?

Comment: No, because it isn't, but you can get there by either defining a variable to be equal to the nonnegative square root of $x$ and using that, or by using $|\sqrt{x}|$ throughout.